# AWS - How to create encrypted Aurora read replica of encrypted MySQL DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to migrate my RDS database from MySQL (5.6) to Aurora. The DB is encrypted. I am trying to follow the process [outlined here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-create-an-amazon-aurora-read-replica-from-a-mysql-db-instance/), but don't have the option to enable encryption.

Elsewhere, documentation for creating RDS read replicas says that the replica will be forced to have the same encryption setting (Yes or No) as the source DB. But in this case, the encryption control for the replica is set to No, and grayed out. I tried various instance sizes, with no change.

[This link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Migration.RDSMySQL.html) says that the encryption option is "Not available," which suggests that encryption is either always on or always off.

But [the FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#security) say "Amazon Aurora allows you to encrypt your databases using keys you manage through AWS Key Management Service (KMS)."  So I remain confused. How do I identify the KMS key, or turn at-rest encryption on or off for Aurora?

Is it possible to replicate an encrypted MySQL DB to an encrypted Aurora DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible with a managed replica, and the FAQ entry probably predates the release of managed RDS for MySQL-to-Aurora replicas... but it should be possible if you set up a new, encrypted Aurora cluster with no data, [and make it an unmanaged replica](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Replication.MySQLReplication.html) of the RDS for MySQL instance, yourself.